# Which type of PHP resource can be shared between a process and its child processes?

Tags: php, sockets, resources, connection, fork

I use the `mysql_connect` or the `Redis::connect` in my parent process. 
After I have forked a child process, the connection resources were lost in the parent process.

Somehow, if I try using a socket resource from `socket_create` function, both the parent and the child process can write to the socket.

I don't know why and how.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice to see some php code - at least the outline of relevant parts

Comment: Err, I want to know if you mean the php origin source code, writing in clang?